# How to see what changes were pulled in Git Extensions?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm using Git Extensions with GitHub.

After I pull, how do I see the list of changes that were just made to my working copy and do diffs (in the Git Extensions GUI or, better, Beyond Compare) on some of the files? Basically, I want what TortoiseSVN shows me in the Update dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all changes between two commits on Git Extensions GUI, ctrl+click the commits. First selection is treated as base, so select older commit first to see the change direction correctly in diff view (additions/deletions).

AFAIK, Git Extensions does not have GUI option to send directory diff to external tool (only file by file), so to get all changes at once to Beyond Compare (assuming you have configured it as difftool for Git), you have to do it from Git bash.

```
git difftool -d <commit1> <commit2>
```

You can omit `<commit2>` if you want to compare your currently checked out version to `<commit1>`. For example, if you are on your local `master` and `fetch` instead of `pull`

```
git difftool -d origin/master
```

will show you changes that will be applied when you `merge` your local branch with `origin`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that selecting 2 commits shows the diff between them. I meant that I want individual file diffs sent to Beyond Compare, so this answer is pretty much what I want, except that I have to manually keep track of which commit I was up to before the pull and find it again.

Comment: @EM If you don't want to lose track of where you were, you should `fetch` instead of `pull` and `merge` or ``pull` after you have reviewed the changes. `git pull` is just a shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. `fetch` leaves your local references and workspace untouched.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest version of git, version 2.6 exposed the `git log --cc` as part of the log command.

Its the same as the diff command output.

#### View changes before the pull / merge

You can view **what is going to be changed** before you actually executing pull using the following syntax:

```
git show dev ^origin/master
or 
git show ^dev master
```

one is stand for pull and the other one is for push.

---

Here is a snapshot of the command output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, "git log --cc" is useful to know. This doesn't give me a nice GUI view of the diff, though.